# Reordering element names based on their position in parent with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="content">

    <div>
        <input type="text" name="newname[name]0"/>
        <div>
           <input type="text" name="newname[utility]0"/>
           <div>
               <textarea name="newname[text]0"></textarea>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="text" name="somename[name]1"/>
        <div>
           <input type="text" name="somename[utility]1"/>
        </div>
        <div>
           <textarea name="somename[text]1"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    ... etc ...

</div>
```

What's an efficient way to use [jquery's selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) to reorder all input elements (input, textarea) based on their current position? ie, if a user deletes `newname[name]0` div from the parent element, then `somename[name]1` would be moved up and should be renamed to `somename[name]0`.

I think it should be something along the lines of:

```
$(".content").children().each( function(index, val) {
    val.find(":input").each(function(i, inputvalue) {
       // Somehow extract the current name of inputvalue and replace the number with index?
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use `.attr('name',...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$(".content :input").attr('name', function(i,oldAttr){
                              return oldAttr.split(']')[0] + "]" + i;
                         });
```

Suppose the format of the value of your attribute `name` is consistent.

### [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/8nDNg/)

In the demo, try double-clicking some input element to remove it, then use element inspector tool of the browser to view the result.

If the `name` attribute has some inconsistent format (there may be some possibility that it may contain more than 1 `]` character) but it always has some index appended at the end, then you can try this more reliable regex solution:

```
 $(".content :input").attr('name', function(i,oldAttr){
                          return oldAttr.replace(/\d*$/,'') + i;
                     });
```

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/8nDNg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could set classes to your elements, and set their names through `.attr`, using the index provided by the `.each` method:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="inp-name" name="newname[name]0"/>
    <div>
       <input type="text" class="inp-utility" name="newname[utility]0"/>
       <div>
           <textarea  class="inp-text" name="newname[text]0"></textarea>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".content").children().each(function(index) {
      $(this).find(".inp-name").attr("name", "newname[name]" + index);
      $(this).find(".inp-utility").attr("name", "newname[utility]" + index);
      $(this).find(".inp-text").attr("name", "newname[text]" + index);
});
```

**EDIT**

You can use some sort of char splitter:

```
$(".content").children().each(function(index) {
      $(this).find(":input").each(function() {
          var name = $(this).attr("name");
          var spl = name.split(']');
          $(this).attr("name", name.replace(spl[spl.length-1], index));
      });
});
```

Comment: If I have many inputs with different names, but has the index appended to the end (ie, `\w+[\w+]\d+` or something), then this way will be very tedious. Is there a way to programmatically extract the current name and just replace its index based on its position?